# Trying to get Ask Ubuntu login to work with LastPass

Tags: discussion, login

I created my Ask Ubuntu login with my Google login, but if I try to manually login with my Google email, and regular Google password (rather than using the "Google" login button), I get "wrong password" (or something similar).  If I can manually login to Ask Ubuntu with my Google email, and regular Google password, then I can use the LastPass entry to login.  Why does this not work?  I am using the correct password as evidenced by successfully logging out of, and back into Google manually, AND logging into Google using LastPass.

Comment: The email and password boxes are for SE openIDs only.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to login to Google first as you have discovered and use your LastPass creds there, then use Google OAuth / OpenID auth to authenticate with SE.

Your LastPass credentials being put into the email and password boxes on the logon page for StackExchange / Ask Ubuntu would be for StackExchange created OpenIDs, if you had registered without using an external logon identifier (Google).  That's why you get the password errors.

TL;DR, you can't use the email/password boxes to logon with your GMail credentials, because that's only for SE OpenIDs if you only register on SE and don't use the external authentication from Google.